# Delete N nodes after M nodes in Linked list L

Tags: c, linked-list

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
struct Node
{
    int data;
    struct Node* next;
};
void push(struct Node** head, int new)
{
    struct Node* new_node = (struct Node*)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
    new_node->data = new;
    new_node->next = (*head);
    (*head) = new_node;
}
void printList(struct Node* head)
{
    struct Node* temp = head;
    while (temp != NULL)
    {
        printf("%d->", temp->data);
        temp = temp->next;
    }
}
void retainMdeleteN(struct Node* head, int M, int N)
{
    struct Node *curr = head, *t;
    int x;
    while (curr)
    {
        if (curr == NULL)
            return;
        for (x = 1; x < M; x++)
            curr = curr->next;
        t = curr->next;
        if (t != NULL)
        {
            for (x = 1; x <= N; x++)
            {
                struct Node* temp = t;
                t = t->next;
                free(temp);
            }
        }
        curr->next = t;
        curr = t;
    }
}
int main()
{
    int M, N, arr[100];
    printf("M=");
    scanf("%d", &M);
    printf("N=");
    scanf("%d", &N);
    struct Node* head = NULL;
    int n;
    printf("No.of nodes in the linked link:");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    printf("Enter the elements of the node\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        scanf("%d", &arr[i]);
    }
    for (int i = n - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        push(&head, arr[i]);
    }
    printf("Given Linked list is :\n");
    printList(head);
    retainMdeleteN(head, M, N);
    printf("\nLinked list after deletion is :\n");
    printList(head);
    return 0;
}
```

It worked for most of the inputs except M=2 and N=1 with L=1->2->3->4->5->6->7->8->9->10. It is showing signal: segmentation fault(core dumped) for this particular input and correct answer for remaining any type of inputs. Why it is not executing for that particular one? or may be there is particular type which are not getting executed.

Answer (score 0):

[It is working fine for me](https://i.stack.imgur.com/meJpT.png) Cause N and M are acting more like counters and less like a pointer.

Although I would recommend adding a check for n>M in main and calling free() more than once can also lead to double caching inside heap which can abort the function. Maybe use realloc(ptr,0) instead of free().

Comment: where I used free() in my code? I'm unable to understand.